# load image with SDWebImage image size greater than imageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, sdwebimage

i am trying make UIImageView with in bubble view.
imageView image load using **SDWebImage** 
imageView size is fixed Width:150 to height:150.

**Code:**

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 //...... some code here
[cell.oMessageImg sd_setImageWithURL:iUrl];
 [cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
 return cell;}
```

What I Want

[image]
**What it shows**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure the views to clip subviews, otherwise some views continue to draw contents outside their bounds.